# Git: Branch of Branch is not fully Rendering CSS

Tags: css, git, visual-studio, branch

I am new to Git. For my project, I have a branch called staging which is a branch off of master. I created a new branch called salesforce_update off of the staging branch. When I am on the staging branch, everything runs and renders well. When I switch over to the salesforce_update branch, it runs fine but when it renders, all of the styling on the page is gone. The data on the page displays correctly and functionality still works. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that the branch `salesforce_update` is up to date with `staging`?

Comment: It sounds like your CSS file has not been included in your third branch.

Comment: @brianna I did a merge with the staging branch and it says that it is already up to date

Comment: @ddsnowboard, how do i check if css files are included. I thought that since I branched off of staging--which is working fine--css inclusion wouldnt be an issue?

Comment: Are you running any task runners like gulp/grunt to create your styles?

Comment: @hidanielle yes, gulp. That's probably the issue, what can I do to resolve it? Never really had experience with gulp.

Comment: @d1du have you tried restarting gulp after switching branches?

Comment: @hidanielle I have resolved the issue thanks to your lead. I still am not sure how gulp works but everything works now. Thank you! Guess I have to spend an hour or so in my spare time to learn gulp and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a task runner to compile your assets you may run into issues when switching branches with it running. Make sure to restart your task runner after switching.